# Does this set has empty interior?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $(\mathbb{R}^2, \tau)$ with $\tau=\{G\subset\mathbb{R}^2:\{-1,1\}\times\mathbb{R}\subset G\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ and the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^1$. If I have understood it correctly, an open set contains the vertical lines $x=-1, x=1$. The solution of the book I'm reading says that the interior of the sphere is not empty, but I can't see how is that, because no subset of the sphere contains those vertical lines. How is that?

Comment: I think you are right. The claim in the book is false.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the exercise?

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @DavidP the question is a true or false statement and says: The interior is empty, and the answer is false, which I found a nonsense